# ImageMagick generates dark images

Tags: image-transforms

Is there a workaround when using Craft with old versions of ImageMagick to prevent transformed images from being darker than the original?

I had a look within the Imagine code base and couldn't see a easy fix.

Unfortunately I'm stuck with ImageMagick 6.7.2-7 on shared hosting with no upgrade path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this option to your [config file](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings) (`craft/config/general.php`)

`'preserveImageColorProfiles' => true`

Comment: That's the ticket! Thanks for pointing that out. I had tried it earlier with no change. I now realise Cloudflare was serving up old images